# Pass value into dropzone sending option after ajax is complete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, dropzone.js

So I am working with dropzone, and everything uploads fine, but now I am to the part of adding the image paths to a database. What I am having a problem with is I first want to submit a form with ajax, after that successfully completes I would like to pass the newly created ID on the database into the sending option of dropzone. Everything works separately, but I can not figure out how to get the new ID into the sending option of dropzone. Here are my 2 pieces of code that are relevant.

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzonePreview", {

    url: "list/post-image",
    parallelUploads: 6,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    processing: function(){
        this.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
    },
    sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {

        formData.append("_token", $('[name=_token]').val());
    }

});
```

and here is the ajax call. I thought I would try the myDropzone.options.sending, but I can figure out how to attach the formData like in the above code.

```
var form = $('form', wizard).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'list',
            data: form,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success)
                {
                    myDropzone.options.sending(null, null, formData)
                    {
                        formData.append("propertyID",         $('[name=propertyID]').val(data.propertyID));
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

hopefully it is just something small that I am missing. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did some tinkering around, and some google searching and I found the answer. Instead of using the sending option, there is an option for params which makes a hidden field. Here is my ajax piece of code that got it working.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'list',
            data: form,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success)
                {
                    myDropzone.options.params = {'propertyID': data.propertyID};
                }
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put ur dropzone proceess queue out of the ajax succeess: like this:
 Dropzone.options.dropzoneJsForm = {
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg,.pdf,.rar,.zip",
        maxFilesize: 2,
        maxFiles: 5,
        addRemoveLinks: true,

```
    init: function () {
        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#btnReg");
         myDropzone = this; //closure
         submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {

             var coursenameID = $('#coursenameID').val();
             var coursetypecodeID = $('#courseTypeCodeID').val();
             var hdcourseexecuterID = $('#hdCourseExecuterID').val();
             //var coursecreationDateID = $('#courseCreationDateID').val();
             var selectedpersons = [];
             $("#doublerow input:checked").each(function () { selectedpersons.push($(this).val()) });

             $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("InsertToDB", "Course")',
                 type: "POST",
                 dataType: "json",
                 traditional: true,

                 data: { "coursenameID": coursenameID, "coursetypecodeID": coursetypecodeID, "hdcourseexecuterID": hdcourseexecuterID, "selectedpersons": selectedpersons },
                 beforeSend: function () {
                     $('#savingdata').addClass('show');
                 },
                 success: function (Response) {
                     console.log(Response);
                     if (Response > 0) {
                         courseid = Response;
                         console.log(Response);
                         $('#savingdata').addClass('hide');

                     }

                 }

             });
             myDropzone.options.params = { 'propertyID': courseid };
         myDropzone.processQueue();
        });

    }
};
```